# Using DMA API in linux kernel but channel is never available

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

I am trying to use dmatest.c to test DMA in intel xeon server and regular laptop with i7 processor.  It is never been able to get a channel - I found this out by debugging the dmatest.c itself. Line 854 below is always executed (I put my own printk there).

Is there anything I should do to get this API to work before executing (such as dma modules or anything?)
Or, do I use wrong API set?
On the Xeon server, I did research and it has ioatdma.ko module that can be loaded. 
modprobe ioatdma
and some files available at /sys/class/dma after that, such as dma0channel0, dma1channel0 .... etc

However, running dmatest code, it still can't get any channel.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

```
       836 static void request_channels(struct dmatest_info *info,
       837                              enum dma_transaction_type type)
       838 {
       839         dma_cap_mask_t mask;
       840 
       841         dma_cap_zero(mask);
       842         dma_cap_set(type, mask);
       843         for (;;) {
       844                 struct dmatest_params *params = &info->params;
       845                 struct dma_chan *chan;
       846 
       847                 chan = dma_request_channel(mask, filter, params);
       848                 if (chan) {
       849                         if (dmatest_add_channel(info, chan)) {
       850                                 dma_release_channel(chan);
       851                                 break; /* add_channel failed, punt */
       852                         }
       853                 } else
       854                         break; /* no more channels available */
```

The test commands that I used (following dmatest.txt document in kernel doc):

```
% echo dma0chan0 > /sys/kernel/debug/dmatest/channel
% echo 2000 > /sys/kernel/debug/dmatest/timeout
% echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/dmatest/iterations
% echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/dmatest/run
```

Comment: Which kernel version you are using? dmatest operates only on channels that provide memory-to-memory facility. You can check usage of the channels by checking `in_use` node under `/sys/class/dma/<channel>/in_use`.

Comment: Andy, on Xeon server, dma0chan0/in_use is 7. What does it mean?   Kernel version 3.10.0. CentOS.  I do modprobe ioatdma first in order to see /sys/class/dma/ files. If not, there is nothing there after boot up.  Is this right way to do it? How do I know which channel provides memory-to-memory facility?

On the laptop with i7, with modprobe ioatdma, there is still nothing at /sys/class/dma

Comment: Find the channel with `in_use = 0` and run test against it. You have to read hardware specification to get know if channel supports or doesn't support memory-to-memory transfers. Or use trial and error method.

Comment: I did reboots and read all dma*chan*/in_use, and all are 7 each reboot. Something is not right. How can I find out which devices are using those all channels?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to supply `dmaengine.dyndbg` to the kernel command line and be sure the `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y` in your kernel configuration. When you boot the machine you will see in the log when channels are acquired. dmatest works only with idle channels.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks. I disabled CONFIG_NET_DMA and all channels available now. I wonder what this config is for.

Comment: Nice catch! That one for DMA'ing skb:s. Actually if I remember correctly Dan Williams removed this in newer kernels.

Comment: I am also trying to do what OP was doing. I have dma0chan0 and dma0chan1 and in_use is 0 for both. But still dmatest is not able to find any channel (I tried both, supplying "channel=dma0chan0" argument to dmatest and not providing that argument (default is all channels)). How do I find if these dma channels support memory to memory operations? Any help would be appreciated if you guys remember anything.