# disabling CONFIG_NET_DMA

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, config, dma

I'm facing the exact problem mentioned in the following thread :-

[Using DMA API in linux kernel but channel is never available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868932/using-dma-api-in-linux-kernel-but-channel-is-never-available)

I'm not able to see any DMA channel in `/sys/class/dma`.  The solution for this has been suggested as to disable the `CONFIG_NET_DMA`. But can you guys tell me how I can disable this particular thing? I checked in make `menuconfig` but got no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output from the search function in `menuconfig` (type `/`)

```
Symbol: NET_DMA [=y] 
Type  : boolean  
Prompt: Network: TCP receive copy offload
  Defined at drivers/dma
  Kconfig:304 
  Depends on: DMADEVICES [=y] && DMA_ENGINE [=y] && NET [=y]  
  Location:
   -> Device Drivers
     -> DMA Engine support (DMADEVICES [=y])
```

So you enter ne menu *Device Driver* and then the sub-menu *DMA Engine Support*. So, press `N` on *Network: TCP receive copy offload*

I took this from a kernel 3.6, but you should be able to find it on any other version.

Probably you can also open the `.config` file and just remove the line `CONFIG_NET_DMA`; it should not have other dependent modules

Comment: Thanks a lot Federico !! But unfortunately, I made mistake in asking the question..CONFIG_NET_DMA is not present in 4.0.4 which is the kernel version I'm working on...Do you have any idea on how to see the available list of DMA channels in /sys/class/dma?? I checked by disabling CONFIG_NET_DMA in version 2.6.32 also, but still I'm not able to see any channel in the /sys/class/dma

Comment: I noticed that they recently remove it. It looks like (I just read a couple of commit messages) was bugged and not compliant with the kernel's DMA API. So is not there any more, in other words is always disable and not available :)

Comment: Yes, What you're saying is absolutely right, But inspite of this being removed in the current Kernel versions, no channels are visible in /sys/class/dma....Do you have any idea about this on how to see the available list of channels so that dmatest driver gets some channel allocated to it??

Comment: I never used dmatest yet. So I cannot help with that. I can only read the manual and guess :/
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmaengine/dmatest.txt

Comment: :) Thanks a lot for your efforts.. I appreciate your efforts...Need to do more work in the direction of fixing it...